# I created a table with react but now I need to send them data from my backend, does anyone know how I can do this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Code Table: I am creating a table that receives parameters as shown in the table header, now I need to get them from the endpoint below, how can I do the data mapping? in the endpoint it receives a date and according to this it shows the data

```
import React from 'react';
        import { Table, Thead, Tbody, Tr, Th, Td } from 'react-super-responsive-table';
        import 'react-super-responsive-table/dist/SuperResponsiveTableStyle.css';
        
const TableComparativeSale = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <Table
      id="tabla-comparativa"
      className="table table-striped table-bordered"
    >
      <Thead>
        <Tr>
          <Th>Id</Th>
          <Th>Tienda</Th>
          <Th>Tipo de Tienda</Th>
          <Th>Fecha año anterior</Th>
          <Th>Fecha año actual</Th>
          <Th>Estado Crecimiento</Th>
          <Th>Estado Crecimiento</Th>
          <Th>Visitas</Th>
          <Th>Boletas</Th>
          <Th>Conversion</Th>
        </Tr>
      </Thead>
      <Tbody>
        {data.map((venta) => (
          <Tr key={venta.id}>
            <Td>{venta.id}</Td>
            <Td scope="row">{venta.nombre_tienda}</Td>
            <Td>{venta.tipo_tienda}</Td>
            <Td>$2.395.990</Td>
            <Td>$ {venta.monto_ventas}</Td>
            <Td>+</Td>
            <Td>43%</Td>
            <Td>{venta.visitas}</Td>
            <Td>{venta.boletas}</Td>
            <Td>33%</Td>
          </Tr>
        ))}
      </Tbody>
    </Table>
  );
};

export default TableComparativeSale;
```

Code ENDPOINT node js and mssql

```
export const TableSales = async (req, res) => {
  const pool = await getConnection()
  try {
    const {fecha} = req.body
    const result = await pool.request().query(`exec [COMER].[dbo].intranet_consulta_venta_diaria '${fecha}'`)
    pool.close()
    res.json(result)
    return res.status(200)
  } catch (error) {
    pool.close()
    return res.status(404).json({ msg: JSON.stringify(error) });
  }
 }
```

Comment: You can get the data from the backend, process it as a JSON, and store it in a way that you have the schema of Headers seperately, and then the content of the body seperately, Then you can directly use that JSON and map the data in the JSX and proceed accordingly.

Comment: where should i do the fetch?

Comment: It is up to you, it can be bound to the useEffect() hook, if it is needed on page load, or you can wrap it inside a button click and use them, anything should be fine. After you get the data, you can set the value to an element using the useState() hook